# remote logging using rsyslog server is not working

Tags: linux, redhat, centos6, syslog, rsyslog

I have 2 linux machines, both of them have rsyslog. I need to send logs from client machine to server machine. I have done these steps but still I am not able to send the message. What am I doing wrong? I am using UDP port 514

SERVER MACHINE : (192.16.72.239)

`updated /etc/rsyslog.conf`, `uncommented 2 lines after comment`

```
# Provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

`restarted rsyslog`
executed below commands as well:
[root@mysystem/]# iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 514  -j ACCEPT

[root@mysystem/]#nc -l -p 514 -4
Ncat: bind to 0.0.0.0:514: Address already in use. QUITTING.
```

CLIENT MACHINE :

`added this rule(third line) at the end of the file:`

```
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
*.* @@192.16.72.239:514
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

now I am using command on client machine `logger "sending message from client to server"`. But I can see above message is present in client's `/var/log/messages` but it is not present in server's `/var/log/messages`.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: The `@@` prefix means use tcp. Use a single `@` to send over udp.

Comment: yes thank you, it worked.